# Why am I getting error No overload for method DisplayAllPeople takes 0 arguments?

Tags: c#, overloading

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GroupOfPeople group = new GroupOfPeople();

        while (IOHelper.AskYesNoQuestion("Do you want to add another person to the array? "))
        {
            Console.Write("Name?   :");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Age?    :");
            int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Person newPerson = new Person(name, age);

            group.AddPerson(newPerson);

        }

        group.DisplayAllPeople();

        Console.Write("Press any key to end the program... ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Below this is the other part of the code:

```
public class GroupOfPeople
{
    private Person[] _people;

    public GroupOfPeople()
    {
        _people = new Person[0];
    }

    public void AddPerson(Person newPerson)
    {
        Person[] _More= new Person[_people.Length +1];
        _More[_people.Length] = newPerson;
        _people = _More;

    }

    public void DisplayAllPeople(Person[] _More)
    {
        foreach (Person i in _More)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Forgot to add this class which contains a display method
How would i implement that method? When i call for it in the GroupofPeople class it says doesn't exist in that context

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name { get; set; }
    private int _age { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        _name = name;
        _age = age;
    }


    public void Display()
    {
        Console.Write("Name : " + _name);
        Console.Write("Age  : " + _age);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I would suggest that your `GroupOfPeople` class should actually inherit `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Person>`.  It will then inherently take on all the functionality of a standard collection, including the `Add` method.  Also, why would `DisplayAllPeople` be displaying people from a `Person` array that you pass in rather than the one already contained in the object?

Comment: Consider declare the `GroupOfPeople._people` field as the `List<Person>` instead of array `Person[]`. Thus you'll be able to use the `Add` method in the `GroupOfPeople.AddPerson`.

Answer (score 0):

re-define DisplayAllPeople like this:

```
public void DisplayAllPeople() //make this changes
{
    foreach (Person i in _people)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("name:"i.name+" age:"i.age.ToString());
    }

}
```

Try : `group.DisplayAllPeople();`

Comment: but when i do that it says that Person[] _More does not exist in the context that DisplayAllPeople is being called.

Comment: When i do that, it just displays LoopsandArrays.Person.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because your method call DisplayAllPeople required parameter to pass and you did not pass that parameter.

I think you have to do something like this.

public class GroupOfPeople
{
    private Person[] _people;

```
public GroupOfPeople()
{
    _people = new Person[0];
}

public void AddPerson(Person newPerson)
{
    Person[] _More= new Person[_people.Length +1];
    _More[_people.Length] = newPerson;
    _people = _More;

}

public void DisplayAllPeople()
{
    foreach (Person i in _people)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

}

Because you already add value to array in AddPeople method. So just use that array.

Note : I suggest you should use collection List. List instead of array so you can avoid array resize problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Two ways to do this**

***1. Solution 1***

Change

```
public void DisplayAllPeople(Person[] _More)
        {
            foreach (Person i in _More)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

        }
```

to this

```
public void DisplayAllPeople()
        {
            foreach (Person i in _people)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

        }
```

***2. Solution 2***

In `GroupOfPeople` add the following method

```
internal Person[] GetPersons()
{
    return _people;
}
```

and change

```
group.DisplayAllPeople();
```

to this

```
group.DisplayAllPeople(group.GetPersons());
```

Even if you get rid of the error, in the end you can not simply use `Console.WriteLine(i)` where i is the instance of `person`.

You have to make the `name` and `age` properties of class `person` to `public` and use

```
Console.WriteLine(i.name); Console.WriteLine(i.age);
```